# Setting the 'pointed finger' cursor for individual rows in an asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm using an asp.net checkbox in a template field in an asp.net gridview. I've styled these checkboxes to use the 'pointed finger' cursor when hovering over a checkbox by including the following in the .css file:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Some of the checkboxes in the gridview will be disabled.  This is set in code using the RowDataBound event of the gridview:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        [various code to set up a chkbox variable]
        if ( [various conditions] )
        {
            chkbox.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chkbox.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The above all works. What I'd like to do in addition is to stop the cursor changing to a pointed finger when hovering over a checkbox that is disabled.  I've tried setting the ID and CssClass properties of the chkbox and including suitable additional CSS statements.  E.g.

```
            chkbox.Enabled = false;                
            chkbox.CssClass = "nohand";
```

And in the .css file:

```
.nohand {
    cursor: default;
}
```

But these don't suppress the pointed finger. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?  Thanks in advance for any help. I'm new here - apologies if this has been asked before and I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: If you are satisfied, please accept the answer. thanks ;)